# global wrapper div min-height 100vh breaks children fixed on mobile

Tags: html, css, wrapper, fixed

In html i'm globally wrapping content with a div.wrapper min-height:100vh; for :target push-left menu, on mobile it breaks all childrens position:fixed; and stick it to the top of page and not to the visible part.

If you have any idea i tried many many solutions..

You can see this at :  http://test.lelabdigital.fr where nav-button-open on the top left corner is position fixed but stick to the top when you scroll bottom.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to stick `aside.mobile-nav` when you scroll ??

Comment: At least the button to open the menu, and for exemple .lightbox inside wrapper/page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.css` 1422 line add `position: fixed;` .

```
body:target aside.mobile-nav {
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

In `main.css` line 1409 try to remove this `style` it will wprk

```
.wrapper {
    transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
    transition: transform .2s;
    will-change: transform;
}
```

You also need to `remove` one more `style` from your `main.css`

```
body:target .wrapper {
    transform: translateX(50vw);
}
```

If you not romve this , then `nav-button-open` will not `fix` when you `sroll`

Comment: @Mathieu Alboré  If this fix , then let me know ??

Comment: Yes but, aside is outside the div.wrapper so it works, but i need to fix element inside the div.wrapper

Comment: @MathieuAlboré You mean you want see `div.wrapper` with full screen when aside visible ??

Comment: No, aside close (invisible) you will see .nav-button-open (hamburger icon) if you scroll down you can see it's not fixed to the top of window it dissapear

Comment: It seems to be transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0); that breaks everything

Comment: Yah also. One more `style` need to remove from your `main.css`.
I update my answer check one more time please.

Comment: @MathieuAlboré  Your welcome . Correct answer desrved UpVote ;)

Comment: Did it ;) (recorded but not public cause i'm not 15reputation)

Comment: That's not a problem ;)